# How to read the lines from a mmap into a dictionary?

Tags: python, file, text, mmap

My mmap opens a json file from disk. Currently I am able to read line by line from the file but I want to be able to store this information into a dictionary of key and value pairs something similar to the structure of the json file contents.

Currently, I use the following line of code to read line by line on Windows.

```
filename = 'C:\Workspace\tempfile.json'
resultsDictionary = {}
with open(filename, "r+b") as f:
    map_file = mmap.mmap(f.fileno(), 0, access=mmap.ACCESS_READ)
    for line in iter(map_file.readline, b""):
        print(line)

# I want to be able to store it in a resultsDictionary so I could use that resultsDictionary in latter method in my python code. I am not sure on how to do this.
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the [`json` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html) from the python standard library.